# MS Graph API: Note Page Results Not Up-To-Date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

When I load pages via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{ID}/pages?$top=100&$orderby=createdDateTime%20desc
```

the results are not up-to-date, even though changes have been synced across other devices.

There should be 4 pages in the section. This is what is in the response:

- two existing pages (two are missing)
- several other pages that were previously deleted, but when I try to fetch the HTML contents, I get a 404. The pages were deleted via `DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{ID}` per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

### Does it work via the OneNote API?

Per @codeye's suggestion (see comments), I'm trying to access the pages via the one note API. It seems unclear whether this is still possible:

- The API is deprecated and scheduled to sunset November 2022.
- [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-auth) refer to registering the application in the [Microsoft account Developer Center](https://account.live.com/developers/applications), which appears to be obsolete and points back to the Azure portal
- Later in the same doc, they refer to permissions like `office.onenote_update` that no longer seem to exist i.e. I can't find them in the Azure Portal. I do see permissions with the same name from two places: `Microsoft Graph` and `OneNote` - perhaps the permissions have been renamed?
  [image: Note permissions in the Azure Portal]
- However, after adding `One Note` ->
  `Notes.ReadWrite`, logging out and reauthenticating, I'm still getting HTTP errors on onenote.com URLs like:
- 401 from `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/{ID}/pages?$top=100&$orderby=createdDateTime%20desc` (as @codeye suggested below, tried with and without query parameters)
- 401 from `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks` (URL from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/dn769050(v=office.15))
- 404 from `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notebooks` (same URL as previous, but with `me/` segment added

Comment: Hard to say, I can't reproduce the issue when deleting pages from section. But I'm trying it on the desktop

Comment: There does seem to be a lag in the api picking up changes at times. How soon after the changes have been applied do you try and  grab the pages? If you retry do the changes eventually filter through?

Comment: It's now several days later and the pages with missing content are still being returned by Graph. I'm trying to run some experiments to see if it makes a difference whether they are deleted via the client or API and also whether it has anything to do with soft delete. Thanks for the dialogue, @codeye & 
user2250152

Comment: Hi Sean. I still see this to a lesser extent in my environment where it sometimes takes 3-4 api calls before a new page is recognised and it has been a major issue in the past. I would lodge an issue in your Microsoft 365 Admin Centre unless someone from Microsoft posts here wanting to help

Comment: One other thing to try would be to access the pages with the onenote-api to see if this returns the correct values

Comment: When I search “OneNote-api”, graph and a JS API come up. Do you mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/onenote/onenote-add-ins-programming-overview ?

Comment: https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/{ID}/pages?$top=100&$orderby=createdDateTime%20desc

Comment: That URL returned a 401 error. I did some more digging into the OneNote API and updated the question with the details.